# Asp.net Core MVC LoginPath not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm setting loginpath as following code in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Content/Index");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Content/Index");
});
```

But it didn't redirect to this path, it keeps redirect to "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"

I read some questions related to this but I can't find any working solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm configuring it in the wrong section. In Startup.cs Configure method, I put following code and it works;

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/giris")
});
```

Comment: Please note that app.UseCookiAuthentication should be placed *before* app.UseMvc.